# zoom in and out functionality by using Draw2d

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, draw2d

Is there any way for implementing Zoom in and Zoom out by using Draw2d? I dont want to use GEF framework. Is it possible to implement by using Draw2d,request you to give some examples or links. A Small change I am adding here. I can use ZoomManager. Butis there any examples avaialbel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put everything in a `ScalableLayeredPane` (or `ScalableFreeformLayeredPane` if you use freeform figures) you can set the zoom by calling `setScale(double newZoom)` on it. `ZoomManager` calls the same method.